# Laptop power jack clicking and sparking

Tags: laptop, power-supply

My laptop charger started making some loud fast repetitive clicking noises. I immediately unplugged it and set it aside thinking I just need to buy a replacement charger (its about 5 years old).

However when I closed the lid of my laptop putting it to sleep, the power jack made two click/spark noises and a visible flash of light could be seen, it did the same thing ten minutes later.

I can't quite figure out how this is happening, whether being plugged into the dodgy charger has done something or if this is fixable.

Any ideas as to whats going on here?

Answer (score 0):

This is very dangerous, take out your laptop battery immediately, being careful not to touch the socket. If you have a macbook or such similar laptop without a removable battery, it's time it went in the bin :( sorry.

Your socket has most likely been damaged physically, either due to the bad power supply (connector) or from you bending it. If you have the technical know how, you can try to repair it yourself by purchasing a 3rd party replacement connector but your best bet is to get it repaired by a specialist.

Comment: Yikes. Just poured money into repairing my dodgy screen, its connector and a broken hinge (this bad boy has taken a beating) I would be sad to see it go like this

Comment: Sorry, I hope you manage to get it repaired or find a new one that you like.